# I can not understand with footer

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Прижатый к низу футер</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #DDE4EA;
        }

        .container {
            max-width: 1250px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .page {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: auto !important;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .wrap {
            padding-bottom: 77px;
            background-color: #000;
            color: White;
        }

        .footer {
            height: 77px;
            margin-top: -77px;
            background-color: #E11;
            color: White;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<div class="container">-->
    <div class="page">
        <div class="wrap">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
    <!--</div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

In this case, `footer` is working as I need (top image), and when I uncomment `div "container"`, footer isn't works (bottom image)

See attached [screenshot](http://i7.pixs.ru/storage/1/7/3/wodivpng_4945270_12320173.jpg):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because you are applying the `.container` class without `height: 100%;` in the CSS, and footer is now contained with `.container`.

Comment: I applied your proposition and have got a same result.

Comment: @Sanprof see here http://jsfiddle.net/Zb7n2/ This answer should of said to apply `height: 100%` to the container except Alex did not clearly point it out

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, I applied height: 100% with other style class. Thank you very much, I could not find a result all day long.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Прижатый к низу футер</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #DDE4EA;
        }

        .container {
            max-width:100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height:100%;
        }

        .page {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: auto !important;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .wrap {
            padding-bottom: 77px;
            background-color: #000;
            color: White;
        }

        .footer {
            height: 77px;
            margin-top: -77px;
            background-color: #E11;
            color: White;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="wrap">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wwlcome to StacOverflow! It would be helpful to write one line before the code explaining the proposed solution